# Google Form Header Size

Tags: css, google-forms

I'm currently embedding a Google Form on my website and am noticing the header image has an incredibly tall height. Does anyone know if there is a way to change this in CSS? or am I stuck with Google's design?

Comment: Your embedding it using an iframe right? You can't change an iframe's CSS. It could be possible with some jQuery, but it's not recommended.

Comment: If you wanted to design your own HTML form, but still send the data to a Google Form, you can do that with an HTTPS POST request.  But if you were going to design your own form, you might want to send the data somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way to do it with the wizard tool of Google Form, fortunately, a nice way to generate the form through HTML, and when you use HTML to generate Google Form, that will make you do whatever you like: adjust the layout the way you love, you may use your own CSS, anything can be doable.

Please follow instruction on this link below:

```
<https://codepen.io/learningcode/post/customize-a-google-form-for-your-website>
```

also, you may check the add-ons on Google Form and select the one that suites your requirements, there is a lot of tools which can help you, but I think the one I posted up is the best option to customize the way you like.

Comment: Avoid to post the same answer to different questions.

Comment: i actully thought am doing good and positive action toward old post , i did not know this would be counted as spam . 
should i remove them ? i only posed on 5 threads and no answer was in any of them